# Continuous, bounded real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need a continuous, bounded real valued function $f$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$ does not exist.
Due to the condition that $f$ is bounded, I'm having trouble coming up with such a funtion.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ seems ok.

Comment: Oh God yes! thanks

Comment: It could be a good exercise for you to show that such a function have to oscillate indefinitely.

Comment: So, I should show it's periodic?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take for example $\sin(x^2)$ which is not periodic, but still bounded and with no limit on $\infty$.

Comment: Right. Could you please define for me what is meant by a function oscillating indefinitely?

Comment: There is no interval of the form $[a,\infty)$ where $f$ is monotonic. Note that this is not a sufficient condition. $\sin(x)/x$ oscillates but has a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: It's a bit hard to define "oscillates indefinitely" until you pin  down exactly what you mean. Do you want $\sin(x) + 0.5x$ to be called "oscillating indefinitely"? How about $\sin(x) + 1.01x$? What about $\sin(x)\cdot x$? Once you get a feel for what you want the phrase to mean, you can start to construct a strict definition.